# Window retains focus when pressing Dock folder icon

Tags: keyboard, dock, input-source

When I click on the Applications folder icon in the Dock and start typing, the previously active window retains its focus. That is particularly annoying when the previously active window is a messenger and I hit enter to open the application. Is that a common issue and, if so, what's causing it and how can I fix it?

Here's a motion capture of it:

[image]

You can see that while the Utilities subfolder is being selected, there's still typing going on in the text editor in the background.

Comment: The motion capture link doesn't appear to work.

Comment: What browser app you are viewing it in? It works fine for me on Safari in macOS and the StackExchange iOS app.